# What is the best way to apply mutiple time zone?

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone

I am struggling to apply session basis time zone in Codeigniter(2.0).

Scenario:

Once user logged in the system I use the lat/lon to detect the time zone ID and set it to a session variable and then call set_timezone() into every controller's constructor.

Ex a helper file which is auto loaded:

```
function set_timezone($timeZoneId='')
{
  if($timeZoneId!="")
  {
    date_default_timezone_set($timeZoneId);
    mysql_query("SET SESSION time_zone = '".$timeZoneId."'");
  }
}
```

My problem is I don't want to call `set_timezone()` in to every controller's constructor. What I want is to call globally instead of every controller's constructor.

Comment: maybe creating a new library and then autoloading it via autoload.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution by using hooks.
1.enable the hooks in config
2.set it  into hooks.php

```
class HookMyHandler {
    function post_controller_constructor() {
        $this->ci = & get_instance();


        //my method name


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should create a parent controller called [`MY_Controller`](http://codeigniter.tv/a-10/Extending-the-core-MY_Controller-and-beyond) that all your other controllers extend. In the constructor of that class you can call `set_timezone`. With this solution the timezone will be set automatically in all child controllers.

Your `MY_Controller` should be stored in `application/core` and should look something like this:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->set_timezone();
  }

  function set_timezone($timeZoneId='')
  {
    // Your code
  }
}
```

Now all your other controllers should extend `MY_Controller` instead of `CI_Controller`. E.g.:

```
class WelcomeController extends MY_Controller
{
  function __construct()
  {
    // This will call the constructor of MY_Controller,
    // which in turn sets the timezone:
    parent::__construct();
  }

  // Rest of your functions...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The another way is,

You can define it inside Library. You can create a library and define this function inside libraries and call it anywhere in the application. Don't forget to load the library in AutoLoad.

Answer (score 0):

As Nikitas said create a library file like below and include the library file in autoload.phpb

```
   class Timezoneconvert
   {
       function set_timezone($timeZoneId='')   {
            $this->obj =& get_instance();
            $this->obj->load->database();
          if($timeZoneId!="")
            date_default_timezone_set($timeZoneId);
            $this->obj->db->query("SET SESSION time_zone = '".$timeZoneId."'");
          }
    }
   }
```

in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('Timezoneconvert');
```

Comment: I don't think this will execute the code. It will just make the function available for use.

Comment: I have got a solution by using hooks.